# Trouble with website login python requests

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been trying this out for a while now, but can't seem to figure out how to login with requests on this website for a scraping project. Not sure if it might have something to do with the csrfToken..? No matter what I try it doesen't seem to work.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the script:

```
import requests
LOGIN_URL="https://example/user/login"
payload={'login':'username', 'password':'password'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    print p.text
    r = s.get('https://example.com/account/')
    print r.text
```

here are the html post fields:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://example.com/user/doConsent" id="consentForm" class="consent-form">
    <input type='hidden' name='CsrfToken' value='' />
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="">

    <form method="POST" action="https://example.com/user/doLogin" id="loginForm" novalidate>
    <input type='hidden' name='CsrfToken' value='' />
    <input type="email" class="mb20" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Email or Profile name">

    <input type="password" class="mb30" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: Did you tried with CURL and replicate requests? Also remember to use file_cookies

Comment: No luck with that either.

Answer (score 0):

If your ‘CsrfToken‘ is empty when you make the actual POST requests, then that's your problem. You need an actual csrf token that matches both the form and the header when you send the data.